# Реализация приложения с помощью retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

Я пишу приложение, чтобы на главном экране был список новостей, потом навигация по видам спорта, для получения инфы надо отправлять get запрос, в ответ прийти json.

Насколько я представляю - навигацию можно реализовать с помощью navigation drawer activity, а работу с сервером с помощью retrofit. До этого ничего подобного не делал, почитал про retrofit.

Вопрос

Как связать нажатие кнопок и получение данных с сервера, что мне прописывать хотя бы приблизительно, или где-то есть инфа почитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть здесь https://habr.com/post/314028/ пример использования retrofit. И потом вызвать в onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) (это метод из navigation drawer activity)

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        App.getApi().getData("bash", 50).enqueue(new Callback<List<PostModel>>() { ....
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```